# How to delete a cached file template in Intellij

Tags: ruby, intellij-idea

I'm trying to work on a Ruby project in Intellij.  I tried creating a new file using the `Ruby Class Template` file type.  However, for some reason when I open the file it opens the file with the application that is associated with the **.rb** extension in my OS config, instead of opening it in Intellij.

**EDIT**:

> Although I still have the issue described below I figured it was worth mentioning that I was able to get `Ruby Class Template` types working by creating a new empty Ruby project first then importing
>   my Ruby project as a new module in the Project Settings. See *Importing a
>   module and configuring a separate SDK for it* ~
>   [source](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/opening-a-rails-project-in-intellij-idea.html)

**END OF EDIT**

I figured out that if I just create a file using the basic `File` type in Intellij and name it with the **.rb** extension then I can open it in Intellij.

So after I figured this out I tried deleting the original file I created with the `Ruby Class Template` type.  This time I created it as a plain `File` type and gave it the .rb extension.  But, Intellij still doesn't associate this as a Ruby file (it still has a ? mark symbol next to the file).  I tried creating  multiple variations of ***.rb** file names and they all work, which confirms the issue is only with this one particular file name.

So I can only think that Intellij has some cached reference of the file name and it's template file type.

I tried searching by `%project_name%` and deleting any results under

[source](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544519-Directories-used-by-the-IDE-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs)   `SYSTEM DRIVE>\Users\<USER ACCOUNT NAME>\.<PRODUCT><VERSION>`

But that didn't work.  I also renamed the cache folder and restarted Intellij, to no avail.

Aside from a complete reinstall does anyone have any advice on if I'm going in the right direction, and if so, where I might find this hidden cache reference?

Comment: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360000140644-cached-file-types-for-file-names

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For those not able to access the link to the solution posted as a comment by @y.bedrov

The provided solution was to check the following

> In Settings(Preferences) | Editor | [File Types](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/file-types.html) check all the
>   registered patterns for Files Opened in Associated Applications:

As I accessed this screen and scrolled to the bottom I found my file.  I removed the file from the list and now my issue is solved. I  can now create this file and have it open in Intellij!

[image]